How should a quiet movement be normalized in an audio sample?
I need to create an audio file of a multi movement chorus and orchestra work.  The first movement is generally loud, with a very loud ending.  The second movement uses only a small ensemble (voices only) and it is far quieter.  It does have a dynamic climax, but this is of a much lesser volume than anything in the first movement.  The third movement uses a slightly larger ensemble (voices and a few instruments).  The fourth movement uses the full ensemble again, with a loud climax.
As I prepare an audio sample of the entire work, how should I approach normalizing it?  Do I normalize each movement to the same level and make the middle movements match the volume of the first and last?  Or do I normalize the entire work and have them be much quieter?  How is this normally done?
If it matters, I'm editing each movement with Reaper using VST instruments; I use audacity for normalizing.

“ It does have a dynamic climax, but this is of a much lesser volume than anything in the first movement.” I think you answered your question right here. I’m not an engineer so I’ll skip any technical discussion and comment instead of answering. Why don’t you choose a similar piece of music you like, import it into your DAW and look at the dynamic curve of the wave file? It should give you some ideas.

I suggest never normalizing. Use compression and limiting to create the leak level and crest factor you want.

Are the dynamics perchance similar to Haydn's "Surprise" Symphony, #94?   :)

@JimL. No, not like that.  No surprise dynamics.  Just a series of big fat dissonant chords at fortissimo in voices and orchestra in one movement, followed by quieter music from smaller forces.

Anecdotally, I usually turn music volume to a level based on the loudest parts so that I avoid long-term hearing damage, but then I lose nuance of quieter parts since I literally cannot hear some of the details

This is very much a question of taste and ideals. The loudness wars are mostly over but it helps the listener to even out the volumes between movements a bit. Could be inside movements as well, using a volume curve is the best way but takes quite a bit of experience to make work.
What I do is the following, according to my taste. Exactly how to do it is dependant on the software I use (Reaper should be fine).

Remove really low frequencies, setting a high pass filter to say 60 Hertz. Unless it has an organ in it, there is very little music there.

Divide the recording into three separate channels: music, announcer speak, applause. Each part will be handled slightly differently. In some programs it works best to keep music on the same track, applying effects to each clip separately. In some it works easier to have each movement on its own track.

Normalize each movement separately to about -3dB Full scale (note this is the first step in setting volume).

The strong movements often have a few peaks going very strong. Carefully using a compressor or limiter may help to keep the peaks down and allowing a slightly lower dynamic range. When there are extreme differences, a volume curve might be needed. Less is more though. After the compression stage I can often add a few dB to the volume for the movement.

Listen to the sound and EQ if necessary to adjust for the room. Often less than ideal concert locations has resonant sound frequencies that are better be reduced, typically in the bass frequencies. Again, less is more. This requires good listening equipment that you really know. (I tend to use open backed "studio" headphones for this).

It might help sometimes to add a little reverb. Any compression or dynamics will influence the "natural" reverb so listen carefully.

Now I switch betwen movements and listen to the transition between movements. Often first movement ends with a big bang, and the second movement starts really quiet. It helps to reduce this dynamic range a bit. There typically will be more amplification for the quiet movements, but not to make the movements equally loud. This is where your taste and the listeners expected equipment will come into play. Listening on a high quality system in a well treated room clearly is different from listening on earbuds on a subway train.



There is no audience yet...  this is an audio sample being shared with the ensemble beforehand

@nuggethead So the goal isn't to sound natural, nor even pleasing, but to help musicians prepare?  (That's probably important enough to be worth mentioning in the question, I think, as answers could be very different.)

@gidds yes, that's the idea.  And to prevent  switching from the second movement back to the first (in a practice session for instance) and blasting someone’s ears because they just had the volume cranked...

@nuggethead Then, the solution is relatively simple, since what you're providing should be a preparation guide: either you provide a recording with consistent volumes (eventually alerting about important dynamic changes), or you explicitly clarify that volumes have been adjusted for preparation purposes (therefore explaining for each movement the approximate dynamic range).

@nuggethead: “audience” here means whoever you’re preparing the audio tracks for, so in this case it is the ensemble themselves, and presumably you’re mainly expecting them to be listening in a relatively quiet/controlled setting.
